# Grouping Document Libraries Under "Documents"

Tags: 2013, document-library

This concerns SharePoint 2013 document libraries. We have just upgraded and are setting up some new sites. In each site's navigation sidebar is an item called "Documents" with a library called "Shared Documents" as a sub-item. When we create any new document library, however, the new library appears right at the bottom of the sidebar and we can't find a way to have all the new libraries appear under "Documents" - we can move the library up the sidebar but not into "Documents". Is there a way to achieve this or is this no longer possible? Document libraries were grouped together in WSS 3.0 and I can't believe that such a useful feature has been removed.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to go to navigation settings, select the Documents folder and add a link to other library under it. But, this has to be done manually for existing libraries and every time you add a document library.

Comment: That's interesting - I didn't know you could do that (I'm still waiting for my training). I'll look into it as a stopgap but I can't see our users being happy with that. Thanks for the tip, though - if it's the only way, it's the only way...

Comment: In the absence of any solutions and as this is a workable workaround I'm going to accept this as the answer. Thanks @ShashankReddyKaram.